# How to get a smooth velocity and acceleration from pixel offset

Tags: image-processing, tracking, spline

I'm working on a movable sensor which tracks(follows) flying objects. I do simple image processing at particular frame interval(dt=40ms) and during that time I find the distance(dx) of objet from centre and calculate velocity( v= dx/dt) and acceleration(a=dv/dt) and give command of a,v to the moving platform.

But I found difficulties to calculate velocity due to noise, it gives erroneous values. The object I'm tracking has a path mostly parabolic/ linear but very high speed. To smooth this velocity I used cubic B spline but no notable improvement..

Any suggestions..

cubic b

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your frame rate is 25fps and it is quite enough to track objects.To reduce effect of the noise, you can try to apply a simple noise filter like Gaussian. Of course, this may introduce some performance problems but you can try this filtering operation only on detected object region in the last frame and hopefully you will get more accurate results.